# Program compiled on Windows Vista is flagged for Win32/Wactac.B!ml by Windows Defender on Windows 10

Tags: c++, mingw, windows-vista, msys

I have a program that I compiled on two different versions of Windows so it can run on more systems:
64bit Windows 10: `MinGW64, MSYS2, SDL2 v2.26.0 and later, g++ 13.2.0 make`
32bit Windows Vista SP2: `MinGW, msys.bat, SDL2 v2.0.3, g++ 9.2.0 make`
The source code is very similar, apart from using https://github.com/meganz/mingw-std-threads to replace std::thread in MinGW in the Windows Vista version.

When I ran the program compiled on Windows Vista on Windows 10, Windows Defender flagged it for `Win32/Wactac.B!ml`. When I made an exception in Windows Defender the program ran fine. I tried to `strip` the exe in msys.bat, but it had no effect other than cutting the file size in half.

I submitted it to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/filesubmission/ under *PUA (Potentially unwanted programs) False Positive* so Windows Defender wouldn't flag it. I am not sure how to interpret the response I got. It listed `(!) Cloud: Program:Win32/Wacapew.C!ml` and `(!) Cloud: Trojan:Win32/Sabsik.FLA!ml` [(Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahrS0.png).

*The submitted files do not meet our criteria for malware or potentially unwanted applications. No detection will be added for these files.*
*More detailed information about the approach and criteria categories currently used by the Microsoft researchers are available here:* https://docs.microsoft.com/windows/security/threat-protection/intelligence/criteria

What do `Win32/Wactac.B!ml` and other things do? How can I configure MinGW/msys.bat to not include `Win32/Wactac.B!ml` in the compiled program?

Comment: You probably can't do much about false positives.

Comment: Just a false positive, and it seems they've admitted it in their response. FWIW, we had a false positive with the exact same virus name for our app compiled on MSVC on Win 10.

Comment: I sometimes make an exception rule for the virus scanner to not scan the directory I am building to (speeds up builds and avoids false positives like this)